# Drawing a Image from Thread

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, runnable

I have got application with class extends `JPanel`. This panel is drawing an Image. here is a code:

```
public class BackgroundImage extends JPanel{

private BufferedImage img;
private File imageFile;

public BackgroundImage(){
    super();

    Samolot s1 = new Samolot(200,200,new Dimension(15,15));
    s1.start();

    imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Katie\\Documents\\Eclipse\\Samolot\\src\\Pics\\img_mapa.jpg");

    try {
        mapa = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);        
}
}
```

What i want to do is a class `ball` which will be extends `Threads`. 
Each ball will be next thread. Balls need to move, for example from left to right by simply incrementation coordinate `int x` which defines X-position of created ball. 
To show that ball is moving i need to draw an image in current coordinates. after changing position, thread repaint ball to next position. What is more i need to add `MouseListener` to my ball, to not make problem harder after click it need just to `System.out.println("somemessage");`

My questions:
where i need to draw my ball? in class `Ball`? or `BackgroundImage`? How it should be look like?
where and how add `MouseListener` to make him works propertly.
how to repaint my panel in every cycle of thread.

here is a code of my `Ball` class:

```
  class Ball extends Thread {

  // The image to display
  private BufferedImage img;
  private int x;
  private int y;
  Dimension dim;

public void run() {
    super.run();

    try {
        while(x<1000){
            Thread.sleep(300);
            x++;
            System.out.println(x);              
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  // Instantiate the panel and perform initialization
  Samolot(int x, int y, Dimension d) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.dim = d;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Katie\\Documents\\Eclipse\\Samolot\\src\\Pics\\img_samolot.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) { }

  }
}
```

I read that i shouldnt draw anything in other threads then my main thread(here `BackgroundImage`).

I was thinking about something like that, however it doesnt work:

`class Ball`:

```
  class Ball extends JComponent implements Runnable {
MouseListener listener;

public void addListener(MouseListener toAdd) {
    listener = toAdd;
}

  // The image to display
  private BufferedImage img;
  private int x;
  private int y;
  Dimension dim;

public void run() {     
    try {
        while(x<1000){
            Thread.sleep(300);
            x++;
            listener.mouseClicked(new MouseEvent(this, 1, 1, 0, x, y, 1, true)); 
            System.out.println(x);              
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  // Instantiate the panel and perform initialization
  Samolot(int x, int y, Dimension d) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.dim = d;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Katie\\Documents\\Eclipse\\Samolot\\src\\Pics\\img_samolot.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) { }

  }
    public BufferedImage getImg(){
        return this.img;
    }
}
```

Class `BackgroundImage`:

```
public class BackgroundImage extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

private BufferedImage mapa;
private File imageFile;
private Ball s1; 
public MapaSwiata(){
    super();

    s1 = new Ball(200,200,new Dimension(15,15));
    Thread t = new Thread(s1);
    t.start();

    imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Katie\\Documents\\Eclipse\\Samolot\\src\\Pics\\img_mapa.jpg");

    try {
        mapa = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(mapa, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);      
    g2d.drawImage(s1.getImg(), 200, 200, 15, 15, null);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("message");
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: here are bunch of posts (by Hovercraft Full Of Eels or MadProgrammer == most active in this topics) with (ended) suggestions to use Swing Timer instead of thread (block repainting) and KeyBindings instead of KeyListener

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Comment: @mKorbel i used ur advices to use Swing Timer. However almost all examples show how to draw on `JLabel`. As u could read in my topic, I want to draw in specified x,y coordinates, and `JLabel` doesnt give me this opportunity. How to use Swing Timer without drawing on `JLabel`?